# data-dialog created dynamically

Tags: templates, polymer, repeat

I'm using polymer 1.0.
I'm trying to open a  with on a clic on an element created dynamically with template repeat.
Here is the code :

```
<paper-button 
     data-dialog="modal"
     on-click="dialogClick">
                Click
</paper-button>
```

and the script (from doc) :

```
dialogClick: function(e) {
      var button = e.target;

      while (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog') && button !== document.body) {
        button = button.parentElement;
      }

      if (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog')) {
        return;
      }

      var id = button.getAttribute('data-dialog');
      var dialog = document.getElementById(id);
      alert(dialog);
      if (dialog) {
        dialog.open();
      }
    }
```

This work only if the value of data-dialog is simple text. If I want to change it by `data-dialog="{{item.dialogName}}"` for instance, it doesn't work. It is not found by the while loop and exit with the if. in the source code of the page, there is no data-dialog in the paper-button.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem when using data attributes on custom elements. You might want to subscribe to [this polymer issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2324).

As a workaround, place the data attribute in a standard element that is a parent of the button and search for that one instead.

Also, you might want to consider using `var button = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget` instead of directly accessing e.target, since the later will give you an element deeper in the dom tree under shady dom.

Comment: I found a way of doing it : instead of "data-dialog", I use "title". Maybe not the perfect solution but in my case it work.

Comment: it seems that doing `<paper-dialog data-dialog$="[[ item.dialogName ]]">` should work as expected, according to the issue discussion.